# Vue.JS router-link params from ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Im trying to create a router-link with vue and when I try to pass a parameter I receive from an AJAX request using axios. But at the moment I load the page i get the notice the parameter is missing and it shows up as undefined. How do i get around this?

```
<tr v-for="obj in fetched">
    <td v-text="obj.isocode"></td>
    <td v-text="obj.name"></td>
    <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'str-route-masterdata-country-edit', params: { id: obj.id }}">Edit</router-link></td>
</tr>
```

---

```
export default {
        name: "starlight-masterdata-country-index",
        components: {StarlightTable},
        data: function() {
            return {fetched: []}
        },
        mounted: function () {

            let vm = this;

            Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/masterdata/countries',
                {crossDomain: true}
            )
                .then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    vm.fetched = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    //TODO: Add flash message to screen to show the api request failed
                    window.console.log(error);
                });
        },

    }
```

Error message:

```
vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:16 [vue-router] missing param for named route "str-route-masterdata-country-edit": Expected "id" to be defined
```

Comment: How does the structure, you receive from axios, look like? Your template expects something like `[{id:123}]` Is this the case?

Comment: What exactly is the error message: `i get the notice the parameter is missing`

Comment: @MattMorgan I have edited the post to include the exact error message the chrome console gives me. My apologies.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Thanks, I accidentially used id instead of uuid. Just a bad on my part

Answer (score 0):

Already solved. Used the wrong property. Needed to be uuid instead of id..